# node.js and v2ray websocket vless

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, devops, vpn

my problem maybe be some complex
i want to develop a v2ray(vless)+tls+websocket server with auth system
i dont want edit v2ray source code
i just want develop a middleware to handle auth with node.js
i wants verify user by username and password and add his ip to white ip list for my vpn port
i dont know how can i do this, i know ip is dynamic and i can re-register and replace it with client automatically
now i have 2 options with 2 questions:

1. can i use ngingx? with nginx i can make a whiteListIP in config file and i can edit it and restart it with node.js app per user register, but it makes a question, for use new config you should restart nginx, it can reduce performance?i dont know nginx restarting how much time need
2. can i register them with node.js and forward them request to vpn port?my mean is my node.js app is a middleware between user and vpn port to  auth requests, requests are websocket connection.
   ty if u can help me